# How to configure PPPoA on Cisco 887

Tags: cisco

We are having trouble with a router which will not bring up the PPP session, and our ISP has advised that we must use PPPoA instead of PPPoE (which we're apparently using according to them).

From the ISP:

> "Line is in Sync showing incorrect PPP configuration. This needs to be
>   PPPoA – LLC – 1/50"

I believe the config we have applied is correct (and in fact we have the identical config on the atm0 interface on a second router at the same site, with the same ISP, which is online correctly:

```
interface Dialer0
 ip address negotiated
 ip mtu 1452
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 zone-member security Internet
 encapsulation ppp
 dialer pool 1
 dialer-group 1
 ppp authentication chap callin
 ppp chap hostname YYY
 ppp chap password 7 XXX
 no cdp enable
 crypto map 01-vpn
end

interface ATM0
 no ip address
 no atm ilmi-keepalive
 pvc 1/50
  encapsulation aal5snap
  pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
 !
end
```

Have we correctly configured the ATM interface for PPPoA? (Even though it's using the pppoe client?

Comment: I would try to use "encapsulation aal5mux ppp dialer" in the PVC context instead of aal5snap.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface ATM0
 pvc dsl 1/50
  encapsulation aal5mux ppp dialer
```

`aal5mux` might be what they're asking for, but that doesn't jive with what they've said. *LLC* is `aal5snap` in Cisco:

```
blue-gw(config-if-atm-vc)#encapsulation ?
  aal5autoppp   Cisco AUTO PPP over AAL5 Encapsulation
  aal5ciscoppp  Cisco PPP over AAL5 Encapsulation
  aal5mux       AAL5+MUX Encapsulation
  aal5nlpid     AAL5+NLPID Encapsulation
  aal5snap      AAL5+LLC/SNAP Encapsulation
```

`show atm pvc 1/50` will show what mode the connection is attempting. (i.e. pppoE vs pppoA)